# How to locate code in PHP inside a directory and edit it

Tags: ssh, find

I've been having problems with multiple hidden infected PHP files which are encrypted (`ClamAV` can't see them) in my server.

I would like to know how can you run an SSH command that can search all the infected files and edit them.

Up until now I have located them by the file contents like this:

```
find /home/***/public_html/ -exec grep -l '$tnawdjmoxr' {} \;
```

**Note:** `$tnawdjmoxr` is a piece of the code

How do you locate and remove this code inside all PHP files in the directory `/public_html/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `xargs` and `sed`:

```
find /home/***/public_html/ -exec grep -l '$tnawdjmoxr' {} \; | xargs -d '\n' -n 100 sed -i 's|\$tnawdjmoxr||g' --
```

- You may also use `sed` immediately than using grep -but- it can alter the modification time of that file and may also give some unexpected modifications like perhaps some line endings, etc.
- `-d '\n'` makes it sure that every argument is read line by line. It's helpful if filenames has spaces on it.
- `-n 100` limits the number of files that `sed` would process in one instance.
- `--` makes sed recognize filenames starting with a dash. It's also commendable that grep would have it: `grep -l -e '$tnawdjmoxr' -- {} \;`
- File searching may be faster with `grep -F`.
- `sed -i` enables inline editing.

Besides using `xargs` it would also be possible to use Bash:

```
find /home/***/public_html/ -exec grep -l '$tnawdjmoxr' {} \; | while IFS= read -r FILE; do sed -i 's|\$tnawdjmoxr||g' -- "$FILE"; done

while IFS= read -r FILE; do sed -i 's|\$tnawdjmoxr||g' -- "$FILE"; done < <(exec find /home/***/public_html/ -exec grep -l '$tnawdjmoxr' {} \;)

readarray -t FILES < <(exec find /home/***/public_html/ -exec grep -l '$tnawdjmoxr' {} \;)
sed -i 's|\$tnawdjmoxr||g' -- "${FILES[@]}"
```